# PHP implode function not working

Tags: php, arrays, string, implode

i have an array and i want to convert this array in comma seprated string by implode function but this is not working. my code is below.

```
 <?php 
$relatedSlides = $result['RelatedSlideshows'];
  $relatedSlides = implode(",",$relatedSlides);
   echo $relatedSlides;
  ?>
```

$result['RelatedSlideshows']; is an array and it is printing perfectly. this is not an multidimensional array. this is simple array. how i do this???

Comment: So what does happen? What *is* in the array?

Comment: what does not working mean?  do you receive an error, or an unexpected result?  elaborate.

Comment: Your code is not working, implode() is working fine.

Comment: First of all, accept the answers to your previous questions.
Second, what exactly is not working?

Comment: What is the value of *$relatedSlides* **before** you make the call to implode?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
 (
  [RelatedSlideshowID] => Array
  (
  [0] => 1036425
  [1] => 1036436
  [2] => 4077598
  [3] => 1036432
  [4] => 1036434                                                                                                                                                    )                                                                               )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpleXML object is **not** an Array.  It is an object that under some circumstances can be treated like an array. [Manual Reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.simplexml.php)

`The SimpleXML extension provides a very simple and easily usable toolset to convert XML to an object that can be processed with normal property selectors and array iterators.`

Try:

```
$relatedSlides = array();
$it = $result->RelatedSlideshows->getIterator();
// Iterate over the values in the ArrayObject:
foreach ($it as $key=>$val)
{
    $relatedSlides[] = $val;
}
 $relatedSlides = implode(",",$relatedSlides);
```

Comment: not working. giving "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: it could also be: $it = $result['RelatedSlideshows']->getIterator(); - post a var_dump($result) to show what the actual structure is.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);
$relatedSlides = $result['RelatedSlideshows'];
  $relatedSlides = implode(",",$relatedSlides);
   echo $relatedSlides;
?>
```

Gives me:

```
Notice:  Undefined variable: result in ******.php on line 4

Warning:  implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in ******.php on line 5
```

Hopefully there is enough implicit tips in there.

Edit:

try:

```
   $relatedSlides = $result['RelatedSlideshows'] -> RelatedSlideshowID;
```

Comment: But that's irrelevant since he said he has the original array in your code and you don't... Thus you get errors.

Comment: I know... the point of my post was that he can either tell us what is $result and so on... or use the error functions and see it for himself what is not working in his code.

Comment: actually i forgot to tell you that it is a simple xml object

Comment: implode takes array not simple xml objects :P

Comment: then how to convert this simple xml object array into to simple array

Comment: Did you try `$relatedSlides = $result['RelatedSlideshows'] -> RelatedSlideshowID;
  $relatedSlides = implode(",",$relatedSlides);
   echo $relatedSlides;` ?

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [RelatedSlideshowID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1036425
            [1] => 1036436
            [2] => 4077598
            [3] => 1036432
            [4] => 1036434 ))

Comment: yes it is giving "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in D:\wamp\www\viewslide.php on line 168"

Comment: ok so what is the SimpleXMLElement Object? is it `$result` or `$result['RelatedSlideshows']` ? The array is actually the `RelatedSlideshowID` property of some object..

Comment: when i print $result['RelatedSlideshows'] using print_r then i get  SimpleXMLElement Object ( [RelatedSlideshowID] => Array ( [0] => 1036425 [1] => 1036436 [2] => 4077598 [3] => 1036432 [4] => 1036434 ))

Comment: Then the array is `$array = $result['RelatedSlideshows'] -> RelatedSlideshowID;` do a `print_r` on that `$array`

Comment: SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [rank] => 1
        )

    [0] => 1036425
)

Answer (score 1):

Something's wrong with your original array then, check [this](http://ideone.com/0gpBR) out.

Do a var dump of $result['RelatedSlideshows'].

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's a result from a mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_assoc().
If you want to implode the array associative array from the result, try implode(",",$result);

But be sure to use mysql_fetch_assoc(), because mysql_fetch_array() returns 2 merged arrays, 1 associative and 1 numeric.